# Añadir a este SELECT un campo mes que me diga el total de que mes es?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mysql-workbench

Tengo una consulta para averiguar el total de los Goals y Amount que ha tenido un empleado al objetivo = 'Visita pisos Alquiler'

```
select e.name,o.name, sum(ov.goal)TotalGoal, sum(a.realAmount)TotalAmount
from Employee e
join Objetive o
on o.employeeId = e.uniqueId
join ObjeVari ov
on ov.objetiveId = o.uniqueId
join AO ao
on ov.uniqueId = ao.objvariId
join Activity a 
on a.uniqueId = ao.activityId
where o.name = 'Visita pisos Alquiler'
and ov.startDate >= '19/10/01' 
and ov.endDate <= '19/10/31'
group by e.name;
```

Pero aparte de que me salga el total de Goals(Objetivos) y el total de Amount(Objetivos que lleva hechos), quisiera añadir un campo que me especifique que Mes es el que le he preguntado.
Como en la clase ObjeVari tengo el mes de Inicio y el mes Final del objetivo,
**¿habría alguna forma de mostrar el mes?**

La salida que me devuelve es esta:

```
name, name, TotalGoal, TotalAmount
'Juan', 'Visita pisos Alquiler', '75', '37'
```

La salida que quiero:

```
name, name, TotalGoal, TotalAmount, Mes
'Juan', 'Visita pisos Alquiler', '75', '37', 'Octubre'
```

tabla ObjeVari:

```
create table ObjeVari (
    uniqueId char(20) not null,
    goal int not null,
    startDate date not null,
    endDate date not null,
    objetiveId char(20) not null,
    primary key (uniqueId),
    foreign key (objetiveId) references Objetive(uniqueId) on delete cascade
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que solo vas a tener un mes en tu búsqueda, puedes probar añadiendo un campo más en el `Select list` con `to_char`.

En este caso:

```
to_char(ov.startDate,'Month').
```

Comment: Lo malo que un objetivo puede empezar y terminar en dias distintos en el mismo mes, es decir el objetivo que tiene un comercial del dia 01 de Octubre al dia 15 de octubre son X, pero esque del dia 15 al 20 tiene otros, del 20 al 25 otros. Entonces cuando intento hacer el to_char me sale un error 1055, que la expresión no esta agrupada

Answer (score 1):

La solución temporal que he dado a esta pregunta ha sido hacer la suma de cada rango de fechas:

```
select e.name,o.name, sum(ov.goal)TotalGoal, sum(a.realAmount)TotalAmount, date_format(ov.startDate, '%m')Mes
from Employee e
join Objetive o
on o.employeeId = e.uniqueId
join ObjeVari ov
on ov.objetiveId = o.uniqueId
join AO ao
on ov.uniqueId = ao.objvariId
join Activity a 
on a.uniqueId = ao.activityId
where o.name = 'Visita pisos Alquiler'
and ov.startDate >= '19/10/01' 
and ov.endDate <= '19/10/31'
group by e.name, ov.startDate;
```

Gracias a la aportación de @ajguerreroDev con la idea de añadir el campo con to_char (en mi caso date_format), puedo mostrar el mes que se ha realizado ese objetivo, pero como dentro del mes hay distintos rangos de fechas del mismo objetivo, pues agrupo por fecha de inicio y hago la suma de cada rango, quedándome la salida asi:

```
name, name,                  TotalGoal, TotalAmount, Mes
Juan, Visita pisos Alquiler, 15,            3,       10
Juan, Visita pisos Alquiler, 20,            10,      10
Juan, Visita pisos Alquiler, 80,            50,      10
```